# WPF: How to control the popup of context menus in a listview/gridview

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, contextmenu

I have a two-part-question, I hope it's ok to ask them both at once.

I have a WPF `ListView` with a `GridView` as it's view.

A while ago I was looking for a way to have a `ContextMenu` in the `ListView` that is only popping up when the user right clicks an actual item of the `ListView`.

All the solutions I found online suggested to put this `ContextMenu` inside the `ItemContainerStyle`, so I did this and it works.

**1. question, the general one**

But now it got me thinking... if my `ListView` contains thousands of items, does that mean I created thousands of identical `ContextMenu`s in memory as well? And if I did, isn't there a better way to get **one** item `ContextMenu`?

**2. question, the specific one** (*obsolete, see the EDIT below*)

Now I try to get another `ContextMenu` to pop up, when the user right clicks on the `GridView`s header, and again all the solutions suggest to put it inside the `GridViewColumnHeader`.

I have two problems with that. First, it again creates identical `ContextMenu`s for each of the columns, and second, the `ContextMenu` only pops up, when the user right clicks on one of the column headers. When there is free space inside the header area (because all the columns don't need all the space available), the `ContextMenu` won't pop up when right clicking on the free space of the header area.

Is there a way to pop up **one** `ContextMenu`, when right clicking the header area of a `GridView`?

I'd prefer the solution to be in XAML only, if that is possible.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

Please forget the second part of the question. I found the `ColumnHeaderContextMenu` property of the `GridView` that is exactly doing what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the following custom controls:

```
public class MTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    public MTextBlock ()
    {// breakpoint

    }
}
public class MContextMenu : ContextMenu
{
    public MContextMenu()
    {// breakpoint

    }
}
```

And the following ItemsControl in Xaml:

```
  <ItemsControl Name="ic" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource res}"/>
```

in which the ItemsSource will be set in code behind.

If you use the following setup

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="res">
        <TextBlock Text="A a a a a ">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <local:MContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Item1">
                        <local:MTextBlock Text="u" />
                    </MenuItem>
                </local:MContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock> 
    </DataTemplate>
```

multiple instances of *MContextMenu* and *MTextBox* will be generated. You can check this by setting breakpoints on the constructors.

However, if you declare the control as a static resource, such as:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MContextMenu x:Key="cm">
        <MenuItem Header="Item1">
            <local:MTextBox Text="u" />
        </MenuItem>
    </local:MContextMenu>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="res">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Background="Transparent" Width="100" ContextMenu="{StaticResource cm}"> 
        </TextBlock> 
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

only one instance of them will be generated. Again check it by setting the proper breakpoints. Note that in this case, if you change the *Text* property of the *MTextBox*, if affects all _MTextBox_es in different _ContextMenu_s.

Comment: And is it possible to only create this context menu once for all items?

Comment: see the edit. Set is as a static resource and it will be created just once.

Answer (score 1):

> if my `ListView` contains thousands of items, does that mean I created thousands of identical `ContextMenus` in memory as well?

No.

You can confirm this by creating your own custom `ContextMenu` type, set a breakpoint in its constructor and debug your application:

```
Public Class MyContextMenu
    Inherits ContextMenu

    Public Sub New()
        Items.Add(New MenuItem() With {.Header = "1"})
        Items.Add(New MenuItem() With {.Header = "2"})
        Items.Add(New MenuItem() With {.Header = "3"})
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="listView1">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:MyContextMenu x:Key="cm" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

The breakpoint won't be hit once for each item that you add to the `Items` collection of the `ListView` so don't worry about this.

And it doesn't matter whether the property is set using a `StaticResource`:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <local:MyContextMenu />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Setting the `ContextMenu` property of the `ItemContainerStyle` is the correct way of associating a context menu with a `ListViewItem` container.